# Getting error of Expecting Value in Azure CLI for deploying Custom Script Extension

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Thanks in advance, I'm trying to deploy custom script extension from Azure CLI from Cloud Shell. But getting error of expecting value. I'm using SAS key to download the PS file. I've tried to use every possible way of adding Protected settings, and Pointing to json but it still gives me an error.
 With the below Azure CLI Command

```
az vm extension set --name CustomScriptExtension --publisher Microsoft.Compute --settings '{"fileUris": ["https://archivewsldisks.blob.core.windows.net/container/newfolder.ps1?sp=rcwd&st=2019-06-20T06:27:08Z&se=2019-07-31T14:27:08Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=oRzT7soN%2B2jvL6CxtYN%2B435B7XJYf05TgyPya2VR43Y%3D&sr=b"], "commandToExecute":powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File newfolder.ps1}' --resource-group "vm-test-group" --vm-name "testvm1" --version 1.9
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW7CW.jpg)

Comment: Do you try to change the command like `"commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File newfolder.ps1"`?

Comment: it's running now, can you please post that as an answer so that i can mark it as solved once extension is deployed?

Comment: Yeah, I will add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, it's just a mistake. The parameter `--setting` expect a JSON value and the command you execute misses the quotation marks in it. Just change the value of the parameter `--setting` like this:

```
--settings '{"fileUris": ["https://archivewsldisks.blob.core.windows.net/container/newfolder.ps1?sp=rcwd&st=2019-06-20T06:27:08Z&se=2019-07-31T14:27:08Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=oRzT7soN%2B2jvL6CxtYN%2B435B7XJYf05TgyPya2VR43Y%3D&sr=b"], "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File newfolder.ps1"}'
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I was editing this in PowerShell hence I didn't noticed the json part. New to Azure CLI.

Comment: @AquibQureshi Then you know it now :)